# What's meant here by "feel it ..... to"?

Tags: meaning

In "The Quick One" by G. K. Chesterton, the author was describing a situation in which, Mr. Jukes, a magnificent big, beaming man, with an equally big and beaming tie-pin, make a funny of someone who went to a bar counter to ask for a glass of milk, saying:

> The commercial travellers, though a kindly race, emitted involuntary noises of pain; a murmur of suppressed jests was heard, as ‘Shun the bowl,’ or ‘Better bring out the cow’. But the magnificent Mr Jukes, **feeling it due to his wealth and tie-pin to produce more refined humour**, fanned himself as one about to faint, and said pathetically: ‘They know they can knock me down with a feather. They know a breath will blow me away. They know my doctor says I’m not to have these shocks. And they come and drink cold milk in cold blood, before my very eyes.’

I can't get the meaning of "**feel it ... to**" nor the **link between his wealth & tie-pin and this behavior**?

Does it means that "he **felt that his wealth and elegant appearance forced him to** produce ....."

Comment: 'feeling it due to this wealth and............' = He felt this his (elevated) standing in the community required him to offer a more polite demeanour (towards the newcomer at the bar) than the bluff travellers.

Comment: @BruceMurray Thank you so much.

Comment: Yes, the it refers to the "to produce etc." It is an unusual formulation....